# Improve search results for at symbol (@)

Tags: discussion, search

In [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), `@` is a special symbol used to extract components from a specific (but common) type of list object. Today [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649603/what-does-mean-in-r) asked for the meaning of this symbol. The question is a near-exact duplicate of [a five-year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908010/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-r) with nearly the exact same title. I closed as a duplicate and pointed out to the user that they should search for similar questions before posting. The OP then responded that they looked for but could not find similar questions.

I guess this is a fair point because [when searching for `[r] "@ symbol"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+%22%40+symbol%22) the result comes up twelfth in the list. Is there some way to improve results so it's easier to for users to find a question based on symbols like this (or this symbol specifically)?

Comment: Yea, use google. Frankly, SE's search engine is mediocre at best...

Comment: Even if SO search were to be improved, the problem is that google search just ignores all symbols - most people probably just search via google (if at all) and don't use the SO search if google finds nothing. I always recommend http://symbolhound.com to people which is a search engine optimized for special characters, but this doesn't help prevent duplicates as it's rather unknown.

Comment: @Cerbrus google search is just as bad if not worse in this case. They usually strip all special characters. If you search google for `r "@ symbol"` the results are all about _"The registered trademark symbol, designated by ® [...]"_ as the `@` is silently stripped, leaving just `r symbol` as the query.

Comment: @l4mpi: https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=r%20at%20symbol Simply replace `@` with `at symbol` in your search. [The question linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908010/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-r) in this OP is the first search result.

Comment: @Cerbrus I know, but I responded for OPs search query which is `r "@ symbol"`. "Use google" on its own won't work unless the query is also changed; which might not be obvious to many people. Also, I don't know how well that works for more complicated things like perl operators...

Comment: I don't know, but google's search is pretty darn clever, compared to SE search. (It understands replacements like that, for example)

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249848/search-using-symbols-is-broken; it used to work before.

Comment: check out [stackse](http://stackse.com)